# If this matrix is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Sorry to ask an elementary (even trivial) linear algebra question here but I have almost forgot every trick in linear algebra and I cannot work it out.

---

I know the identity matrix $I$ is positive definite.

Suppose we have a matrix $P$ whose entries are all in $[0,1]$. (Entries of $P$ are just the probabilities of something).

Now we have a $\lambda\in(-1,1)$.

Do we have $I-\lambda P$ is positive definite? (Actually invertibility is enough for my study)

**Edit.** What if we impose an additional condition that all row sums of $P$ are equal to $1$?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It is pos def for lambda sufficiently small (if $P$ is symmetric), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix for invertibility and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem  for control on eigenvalues

Comment: @CalvinKhor Hi Calvin, thanks for the reference. Unfortunately $P$ is not symmetric in my case. Do we have similar result/control for non-symmetric $P$? Invertibility results are enough.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @user1551 Alright. We can put the important extra conditions into the edit section but do not just delete it.

Comment: none of the two results I said care if the matrix is pos def, but it is impossible for $I-\lambda P$ to be symmetric (a requirement for pos def) if $P$ is not symmetric

Comment: I would call it $\gamma$ instead, as $\lambda$ is kind of reserved for eigenvalues. Also, think of the symmetry (or lack thereof).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the advice. I was mainly working with probability stuff and didn't realize the notation may cause confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set of invertible matrices is open (preimage of $\Bbb R\backslash \{0\}$ by determinant function). Therefore, for small enough $\lambda$, $I-\lambda P$ is invertible.

If you add the extra condition that $P$ is [stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), then $I-\lambda P$ is invertible for $\lambda\in(-1,1)$. That's because the largest eigenvalue (in absolute value) of a stochastic matrix is $1$. (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40320/proof-that-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-stochastic-matrix-is-1)).

And there is a little notational trap in your question: $I-\lambda P$ is invertible iff $\frac1\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $P$.

Therefore, if $|\lambda|<1$, $\frac1\lambda$ can't be an eigenvalue, and $I-\lambda P$ is invertible.

Comment: You probably meant to say "it's *not* an eigenvalue of $A$"

Comment: @lcv Right, thanks! ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks Jean. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi Jean, sorry to comment on your old post. I was reviewing some materials and came back to this post. I suddenly couldn't figure out why the condition that, the largest eigenvalue (in absolute value) of a stochastic matrix $P$ is $1$, can lead to the invertibility of $P$. I searched a bit and found [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3552969/507382) using the spectral theorem which I didn't know. Can you give me an alternative proof of this implication without involving the spectral theorem? Many thanks.

Comment: @SamWong A matrix $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$ iff $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. If $A$ is stochastic, its eigenvalues are $\le1$ in absolute value. Therefore $\det(A-\lambda I)\ne0$ if $|\lambda|>1$. That's just from the definition of an eigenvalue. Therefore, $\det(\frac1\lambda A-I)\ne0$ if $|\lambda|>1$, or equivalently $\det(\lambda A-I)\ne0$ if $|\lambda|<1$. Therefore if $|\lambda|<1$ the matrix $\lambda A-I$ is regular, and so is $I-\lambda A$.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not necessarily positive definite or invertible.  For example, try $\lambda = 1/3$ with
$$ P = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 1 & 1\cr}$$

Comment: Yea, you are right. What if the entries of $P$ can not be all the same? (Because in my study, such $P$ can not happen). I will put this extra condition into the edit.

Comment: If you want an example where the entries of $P$ are not all the same, subtract different sufficiently small positive numbers from each of the $1$'s, and then adjust $\lambda$ as necessary.

Comment: Make sense. I will think of my model again. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Robert, I just reviewed my probability model and found one more missing condition in my case. If we require the row sum of $P$ to be $1$ for all rows, do we still have the non-invertibility result for $P$?